# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_grad_cam.metrics'

Tags: pytorch

Pytorch Grad-Cam was working well with my resnet18 models till 23rd of Aug 2022. Suddenly from today, 24th Aug I am constantly getting this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_grad_cam.metrics'

when I run the code in both, colab and spyder:

```
from pytorch_grad_cam import GradCAM, HiResCAM, ScoreCAM, GradCAMPlusPlus, AblationCAM, 
                                                       XGradCAM, EigenCAM, FullGrad
from pytorch_grad_cam.utils.model_targets import ClassifierOutputTarget
from pytorch_grad_cam.utils.image import show_cam_on_image
from torchvision.models import resnet18
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

try to install: pip install pytorch-gradcam

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with [this commit](https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam/commit/60cf39d6eb0e344d6921e62d42399a7fdf7cde57). You can install the latest version of the package and try again.

Answer (score -1):

pip install pytorch-gradcam
it will be worked

Comment: There's an answer from nearly a year ago that already says this. Please don't repeat answers.